# Can i perform controller's integration testing with Spring 3.1?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-test, spring-test-mvc

Currently there is Spring 3.1 on the project i work on.

Earlier i worked with Spring Boot and used `@WebAppConfiguration` annotation to start web application context and perform integration testing of endpoints. Is it possible at all to do the same with Spring 3.1?